# CollectionViewController not adjusting for keyboard showing with InputAccessoryView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikeyboard, inputaccessoryview

I have a chat page in my app, and am using an InputAccessoryView for the textfield. When the keyboard opens and closes the textfield follows the keyboard and looks great. The issue is that when the keyboard opens, the collectionview does not adjust to allow scrolling to the end of the content.

Any ideas what could be causing this issue?

```
func handleKeyboardWillShow(_ notification: Notification) {
    let keyboardFrame = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as AnyObject).cgRectValue
    let keyboardDuration = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as AnyObject).doubleValue

    containerViewBottomAnchor?.constant = -keyboardFrame!.height

    UIView.animate(withDuration: keyboardDuration!, animations: {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }) { (Bool) in
        let indexPath = IndexPath(item: self.messages.count - 1, section: 0)
        self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)
    }

}

func handleKeyboardWillHide(_ notification: Notification) {
    let keyboardDuration = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as AnyObject).doubleValue

    containerViewBottomAnchor?.constant = 0
    UIView.animate(withDuration: keyboardDuration!, animations: {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Making collection views and keyboards work together is a pain with many quirks.

The easiest thing to do is either use [TPKeyboardAvoiding](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding) by [Michael Tyson](https://github.com/michaeltyson) or look at the code to see what it's doing.